# Tried to send a platform message to Flutter, but FlutterJNI was detached from native C++. Could not send. Channel:

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin

I am trying to track the location of the device in terminated state also. Tried using flutter pluggins and also native code. In both the cases I get
"Tried to send a platform message to Flutter, but FlutterJNI was detached from native C++. Could not send....."

Can anyone please give me pointers.